# AWS, Static IP on Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function (NodeJS) which consume an API that need to be accesed from certains IP, so team under the API ask me "please, provide us your IP to add it to the white list", but I'm not sure where or how to configure that static IP on AWS, where should I look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since @maurice show you the way, I will try to add some insight though I had to build a similar infrastructure like yours:
Third party provider requests us a static IP to connect to their API and our code was in a Lambda function (NodeJS).

In this case we did not want the lambdas to be reachable from outside, so we built two Subnets, one private and another one public. Lambdas go inside the private, which route Table 0.0.0.0/0 uses a NAT attached to the public subnet to manage the traffic that needs to connect to the Internet. Let me show you a few screenshots:

1. The Lambda must be in a VPC subnet with a NAT-Gateway.
   [image]
2. The private subnet route table, which shows a NAT attachment:
   [image]
3. The NAT belongs to the public subnet, and has an elastic IP attached (this is the key):
   [image]
4. The public subnet has the following route table (everything is managed by the IGW):
   [image]

This is something that is currently running in production environment and works flawless

Answer (score 2):

You can't provide a static IP in a Lambda function directly.
You could deploy the Lambda function in a private subnet of a VPC that uses a NAT-Gateway for internet connectivity.

This NAT-Gateway will have an Elastic-IP, which you can tell your provider
(For high-availability you should have one NAT gateway per region).

Comment: Something like this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html or this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appstream2/latest/developerguide/managing-network-internet-NAT-gateway.html